# Fade in web elements on page load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to get a main logo and then an enter button to fade in when this web page loads. Tried the below code in addition to taking the divs out after the code, but no luck.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>

    <title>The Webspace of Reality</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

 </head>
 <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function() {

            $("#mainImage").hide().fadeIn("slow", function() {
                $("#enterButton").hide().fadeIn("slow")
            });
        });

    </script>
    <div id="mainImage">
    </div>
    <div id="enterButton"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

```css
#mainImage img {
    width: 550px;
    display: block;
    position: static;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#enterButton button {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Futura, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: fading works here, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/zkf4wucg/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in css. The commas are added after name selectors:

```
#mainImage, img {
    width: 550px;
    display: block;
    position: static;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#enterButton, button {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Futura, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    color: white;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your script tags:

```
$("#mainImage, #enterButton").hide();
$("#mainImage").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $("#enterButton").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bboysupaman/djfdgypc/).